# Using Terraform commands in JenkinsPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to terraform stuff and currently working on running terraform scripts on JenkinsPipeline. I have some `.tfvars` file for each region for example `tf-de-sandbox.tfvars, tf-fr-sandbox.tfvars, tf-de-prod.tfvars, tf-fr-prod.tfvars`. I am trying to run `plan` and `apply` commands through JenkinsPipeline. What I am looking for is there anyway where I can run both sandbox files in parallel and prod files in parallel. Forexample can I give multiple tfvars file while using `plan` command?
`Terraform plan -var-file=[tf-de-sandbox.tfvars,tf-fr-sandbox.tfvars]` or something like this and then use `apply` command?

My JenkinsPipeline looks like this.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    triggers {
            cron('0 9 * * *') //schedule your build every day at 9h 00
        }
    stages {
        stage('Pre-deploy stacks') {
          agent { node { label 'deploy-python36' } }
            steps {
              sh 'cf sync --confirm cfn/stacks.yml'
              sh 'curl https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/AmazonLinux/hashicorp.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/hashicorp.repo && yum install terraform -y'
            }
        }
        stage('TF Initialization') {
          agent { node { label 'deploy-python36' } }
            steps {
              dir('./tf') {
                sh 'terraform init'
              }
            }
        }
        stage('TF/DE planning [box]') {
          agent { node { label 'deploy-python36' } }
            steps {
              dir('./tf') {
                sh 'terraform plan -var-file=conf/tf-de-sandbox.tfvars'
              }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example:

```
terraform plan --var-file=dev.tfvars --var-file=common.tfvars --out=planoutput
```

And then, to apply:

```
terraform apply planoutput
```